# How to derive $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}$ from $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$

Tags: limits, exponential-function

Is it possible to derive

\begin{align*}
e=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}
\end{align*}

from

\begin{align*}
e=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
\end{align*}
?

Thank you:)!

Comment: It boils down to proving $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!} \left(1-\frac{n(n-1)\ldots(n-k+1)}{n^k} \right)=0$$ which should be doable.

Comment: You should be able to prove that by dominated convergence with respect to the counting measure.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM: using measure theory / dominated convergence to prove a minor result is almost like using a cannon to kill a firefly.

Comment: Thanks for the fix in the formulas!:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the binomial expansion you get $$\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n=1+n\cdot \frac 1n+\frac {n(n-1)}{2!}\left(\frac 1n\right)^2+\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}\left(\frac 1n\right)^3\dots=$$$$=1+1+\frac 1{2!}\left(1-\frac 1n\right)+\frac 1{3!}\left(1-\frac 1n\right)\left(1-\frac 2n\right)+\dots$$

I will leave you to conclude.

Comment: The conclusion in your answer is what OP has to prove. So your proof is probably not working well at least to OP and then MSE community.

Comment: @DeepSea All I have done is indicated how the binomial expansion can be rewritten - I have assumed the binomial expansion is known. It is clear that this converges term by term to what is wanted, but there is a bit more work to show global convergence. This way of rewriting the expression seems to me to be a helpful way of seeing how everything fits together. So I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Well the missing piece is to use the monotone convergence theorem. Without that or something similar it is difficult to prove the desired result.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh This expansion shows why the limit is what it is. Given that the limit of the original expression is known to be $e$ and (not difficult) $(\frac 1n)^n$ is increasing you have an increasing bounded sequence of numbers, which must therefore converge. My point is that this is a useful (I'd say 'key') step in doing what the question asks, which is to "derive" the series expansion from the limit (not "prove"). If I know the expansion I can prove it, but how do I find out what it is in the first place?

Comment: Agree! I just added how this could be completed into a full proof via monotone convergence.

Answer (score 2):

A simple idea is to show via the use of binomial theorem that $$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\leq\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\leq\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$$ and then note that both the first and last terms in the inequality above tend to same limit so that sum in middle also tends to the same limit via Squeeze Theorem.